# After segue ViewDidLoad is called but ViewWillAppear and ViewDidAppear is not being called

Tags: xcode4.3, segue, viewdidappear

I have created a segue in storyboard named "CreateGame".And called it with my viewController to Load CreateGameViewController using`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CreateGame" sender:nil]`  but is is not working. it was working some time ago but suddenly it is not working.

I have taken a look of my code. My

`-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
NSLog(@"Segue");
}`

is being executed each time when i call `[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"CreateGame" sender:nil]`and then CreateGameViewController's`"viewDidLoad"`  is being executed (conformed by using NSLog(); statement) . but CreateGameViewController's `ViewWillApper` is  not  being called.

i am using NavigationController So type of segue is 'Push'. some times segue works or sometimes not. Please help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are doing something in your `CreateGameViewController's "viewDidLoad"` (may be some looping or some recursion function calling without end) . That would have prevent the screen appears. it would be more helpful if you can provide the code of `CreateGameViewController's "viewDidLoad"`